# Analog inverting amplifier

Tags: buffer, inverting-amplifier, gilbert-cell

I know that in a gilbert mixer, you need to input the LO and an inverted LO.

Assuming the signal is about 100 mhz.

How could the signal be inverted, while keeping with the original amplitude, without an Op Amp?

The key is to not distort the shape of the signal, while inverting it.

Options I thought of:

1. Op Amp - but typically doesn't support 100 mhz
2. Common Emitter - won't keep a unity gain to voltage (especially if the hfe or beta of the transistor is uncertain).
3. Differential Amplifier - seems like the most promising option as the voltages across the two load resistors are inverted.

Are there any other fairly simple ways to invert an anslog signal?

Thanks kindly..

Edits:

1. The single transistor phase splitter idea suggested in a comnent is simpler than option 3 above (using a diferential amplifier). Thanks for the suggestion.
2. In an answer below, it is suggested that a Gilbert cell could be fed with a signal relative to ground, and not to its inverse. Would that hold generally or is it an enhancement provided by the NE602 to the basic Gilbert mixer?

Comment: Have you looked at operational transconductance amplifiers?

Comment: If it's periodic you can delay it by half the period.

Comment: something along the lines of a phase splitter, but with smth to cancel the base current?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_splitter   follow the link at the bottom of the wiki, under external links...

Comment: Pete - that's the easy solution I was looking for. If Rc = Re, I don't need to know the beta of the transistor. Thanks kindly.

Comment: Heath - thanks for your comment. Is there perhaps a link with more info on this kind of a delay circuit?

Comment: Transformer couple it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not necessary to feed either the RF port or the LO port differentially.

One input can be connected to AC ground with the signal being fed in single-ended to the other.

If you do wish to feed the inputs differentially to get better balance and  LO suppression a center-tapped transformer or Balun (balanced to unbalanced converter) is commonly used - at RF frequencies they can be small.

A non-center tapped transformer may also be possible if the DC bias conditions of the input stage can be met.

Opamps are very rarely used at these frequencies as they don't have enough gain to work effectively.

[image: RF Mixers - Iulian Rosu]
[RF Mixers - Iulian Rosu](https://www.qsl.net/va3iul/RF%20Mixers/RF_Mixers.pdf)
[image]

[NE602 Experiments](https://sites.google.com/site/radiolabrio/short-wave-ne602)

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your answer - would it be the case that for a basic gilbert cell (without any extras NE602 provides) the differential feeding is merely an enhancement and it would work Ok with the other end being simply ground? That would circumvent the issue altogether.

Comment: @Daniel - I would think the balance would not be as good when feeding single ended, depending upon the common-mode rejection of the device. As I mentioned a transformer is a common way to create the differential signal.